# UWP Grid Manipulation Overlay

Tags: grid, uwp, swipe-gesture

I'm having trouble with *Grid* Overlays in UWP Apps.
I have the following Control (without *ColumnDefinitions* for better viewing):

[image: Control]

```
<Grid>
  <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" Tapped="doneGrid_Tapped">
    <TextBlock Text="fertig" Foreground="Lime" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  </Grid>

  <Grid Grid.Column="3" Background="Transparent" Tapped="allGrid_Tapped">
    <TextBlock Text="alle" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  </Grid>

  <Grid Grid.Column="5" Background="Transparent" Tapped="undoneGrid_Tapped">
    <TextBlock Text="ausstehend" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
  </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Which is working nice. I can tap one of the three areas and it triggers the *Tapped* event from the *Grid*. Now I want to go a step further and also include a "swiping gesture".

So I put a *Grid* on top of that:

```
<Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Background="Transparent" ManipulationMode="TranslateX" ManipulationStarted="..." ManipulationCompleted="..." />
```

Now I can swipe left and right, but my *Tapping* does not work anymore, only swiping.

How can I make Tapping AND swiping both work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it, when you put a `Grid` use `Grid.ColumnSpan = "7"` after your other grids, you actually put a `Grid` on top of the others, so you can only get the focus of this `Grid`. When you put a `Grid` use `Grid.ColumnSpan = "7"` before your other grids, it is on the lower level of the others, it can be manipulate outside gird3, grid5, and grid7, and these 3 grids can be tapped, but when you want to start manipulate from grid3, 5, 7, it can't work. To achieve your expect, youdon't need to add any `Gird` use `Grid.ColumnSpan = "7"`, you just need to manipulate that like this:

```
<Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid ManipulationMode="TranslateX" ManipulationStarted="manipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="manipulationCompeleted">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Column="1" Background="Transparent" Tapped="doneGrid_Tapped">
            <TextBlock Text="fertig" Foreground="Lime" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="3" Background="Transparent" Tapped="allGrid_Tapped">
            <TextBlock Text="alle" Foreground="Gray" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>

        <Grid Grid.Column="5" Background="Transparent" Tapped="undoneGrid_Tapped">
            <TextBlock Text="ausstehend" Foreground="Red" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        </Grid>

        <!--<Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="7" Background="Transparent" ManipulationMode="TranslateX" ManipulationStarted="manipulationStarted" ManipulationCompleted="manipulationCompeleted" />-->

    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Now you can tap them or swip the `Grid`. 
Wish this helps you.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is working like charm and much simpler than expected.